# libavg compliation error

Tags: opensuse, opensuse-12.2

I have downloaded libavg from https://www.libavg.de
When I do ./configure it gives me error

```
checking for libpython2.7... configure: error: could not find files required to build python plugin
```

I have installed libpython2.7_1.0 and python-devel.
I am using OpenSUSE 12.2 (64 bit).Help.

Answer (score 0):

At least, I can reproduce this behaviour ...

```
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python platform... linux2
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking for headers required to compile python extensions... found
checking for libpython2.7... not found
configure: error: could not find files required to build python plugin
```

It appears to me that there is something broken in how the packages are organized (maybe some Python 2 vs. Python 3 issue). Maybe it is a good idea to post the issue here: http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-factory/

Comment: But I am not using any factory repo? Where should i report the issue?

Comment: You are right, but IF this happens due to "design" problems within the packages, it may actually be good to post it to kind of the main developer mailing list. Most people in the project read the factory list.